# Autowired beans in EnvironmentProcessor are null

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-vault, java-cfenv

I am using `spring-vault` and specified PostProcessor that supposed to do some custom operations on Vault

```
@Profile("cloud")
@Component
public class VaultPostProcessor implements EnvironmentPostProcessor, Ordered {
    private static final String VERSION_BACKEND_PREFIX = "^/v1/";
    private int order = ConfigFileApplicationListener.DEFAULT_ORDER + 2;

    @Autowired
    private VaultTemplate vaultTemplate;
    @Autowired
    private VaultCloudProperties vaultCloudProperties;

    @Override
    public void postProcessEnvironment(ConfigurableEnvironment environment, SpringApplication application) {
        MutablePropertySources sources = environment.getPropertySources();
        sources.addFirst(new VaultPropertySource(vaultTemplate,
            vaultCloudProperties.getServiceSecretPath().replaceAll(VERSION_BACKEND_PREFIX, "")));
        sources.addFirst(new VaultPropertySource(vaultTemplate,
            vaultCloudProperties.getSpaceSecretPath().replaceAll(VERSION_BACKEND_PREFIX, "")));
        sources.addFirst(new VaultPropertySource(vaultTemplate,
            vaultCloudProperties.getOrgSecretPath().replaceAll(VERSION_BACKEND_PREFIX, "")));
    }

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return order;
    }
}
```

I added post processor in `spring.factories` and it being picked up just fine.

However both `VaultTemplate` and `VaultCloudProperties` are null. `VaultTemplate` is provided by Spring Vault, while VaultCloudProperties is my `ConfigurationProperties` object.

```
@Profile("cloud")
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("core.applicaiton.vault")
public class VaultCloudProperties implements Aware {
```

What might be the issue for the beans to be null?

Comment: The `EnvironmentProcessor` is picked up very early in the proces and as such isn't subject to auto wiring.

Comment: @M.Deinum I see. Then I wonder how I can add these property sources (that requires VaultTemplate) before other beans are created

Comment: You got a chicken and egg problem here. As this is executed before everything is fully configured and the configuration you retrieve could influence yuor properties and template you are using. (You now probably refute this that this will never happen, but from a Spring (Boot) perspective it can). I suggest you use Spring Cloud Vault which does configuration out-of-the-box for you and saves you from writing this yourself.

Comment: @M.Deinum isn't spring cloud vault more meaty (in dependencies) than spring vault dependency?  we actually originally used spring cloud vault + cloud connectors but decided to migrate to java-cfenv and remove spring cloud dependencies altogether

Comment: @M.Deinum considering that Spring Cloud Vault achieves, so it is possible to do? basically we want to read properties from "vault" and then use them to instantiate other beans

Comment: No it isn't as accessing the vault doesn't mean the template is used or it can be used but not autopwired. THe problem here is the autowiring, you can instantiate the template yourself for single use. Nonetheless why reinvent the wheel?